# If the Hessian matrix is symmetric is $\mathscr C^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I know that, if $ f (x)$ is a $\mathscr {C}^2$ function, then the Hessian matrix is symmetric.
But if the matrix is symmetric could not be $\mathscr {C}^2$; can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your favorite twice differentiable function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ which is not in class $\scr{C}^2$. For instance, use 
$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(1/x)&x\ne 0\\
0&x=0.
\end{cases}$$
Then take a primitive of it, i.e. define $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf(t)dt$ so that $F'(x)=f(x)$. Now $F(x)$ is once continuously differentiable and twice differentiable but not twice continuously differentiable. Anyway, define a function $(-1,1)\times (-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $G(x,y)=F(x)$. It has Hessian 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f'(x)&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is symmetric, but yet the function is not $\mathscr{C}^2$.